# Test controller with null_session in rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, cancan

My Rails4 ApiController is set up as follows so as to allow it to be CURLed (to avoid CSRF token issues)

```
class ApiController < ApplicationController
  protect_from_forgery with: :null_session
```

Now, I wish to write an rspec test to confirm that actions in controllers that inherit from ApiController, run successfully even when there is no csrf token (like in curl requests).
Is there a way to simulate this `:null_session` in rspec tests?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing something, simply **NOT** supplying a value for the CSRF token is sufficient to *test*.

Comment: Unfortunately request and controller specs automatically add in the CSRF token as far as I know. What would help is to figure out how in a request spec to set the CSRF token to null or missing so that we can test that API controllers work without throwing an ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken